# Logitech g9 mouse, the scroll click doesn't work?

Tags: windows-7, logitech-mouse

On my Logitech g9 mouse, when I click on the scroll wheel, while hovering over a link, doesn't open up a new window.

My older mouse did, I installed the latest driver for Windows 7 yet it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you tell me what scan code it is sending, using the method I posted in this question? http://superuser.com/questions/66993/change-internet-hotkey/66997#66997

Answer (score 1):

Logitech mice rely on SetPoint for any extra functionality (like what you describe). If you have the program installed, check to see if that particular button maps to the correct task.