# Bind a hotkey combination to command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way I can bind a keyboard combination (for example <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>) to launch the command prompt in Windows 7?

Comment: I believe your question has been answered [here](http://superuser.com/questions/66993/change-internet-hotkey)

Answer (score 5):

Find a **Command Prompt** GUI icon. There's one located in `Start` > `All Programs` > `Accessories` by default. Right-click it and select `Properties` from the context menu. Enter some unused key combination in the "Shortcut key:" field.

My keyboard doesn't have a Windows key, so I don't know about the specific combo you requested, but I confirmed that this works in the general case with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: This unfortunately cannot start a second instance of the same program -- instead, it is brought to the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

Well the second best thing is this:

1) Hit "WinKey + R" to launch the run-software (or whatever it is called)

2) Type "cmd" into the run command-line. Then hit "enter"

This will launch the command prompt. Whatever was your last launch-command will be saved there. In this scenario, you've only ever typed in "cmd". Next time you only have to hit "WinKey + R" and then "Enter" to launch the prompt, as the "cmd" will be there when you start run-commandline.

E.g. I use it to instantly open a private window in firefox by inserting "firefox -private-window" into the command line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following will allow you to create a persistent hotkey that will open a new CMD window every time you press it.  As another user noted, one of the other answers allows you to create one new CMD window with the hotkey, but subsequent presses just bring that window into focus instead of creating additional windows.

### Ensure Shortcut Hotkeys Persist

In order to make sure your hotkey configuration persists across reboots, create a new folder called `_hotkeys` at this location:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
```

### Create Batch Script to Open a CMD Window

1. Open up the new `_hotkeys` folder, and inside of it create a new file called `start_cmd.bat`
2. Open start_cmd.bat, enter the following, and save it:

   ```
   @echo off
   start cmd
   ```

### Create a Shortcut to the Batch Script

1. Right-click the `start_cmd.bat` file and select `Create Shortcut`
2. Right-click the new shortcut file and select `Properties`
3. Set your desired hotkey using the `Shortcut key` box